# Using pypy or pypy3 instead of python3 make sense?

Tags: pypy

i have a longer python3 (running 3.10)script with any libraries and classes and like to speed up. After some optimiziation a read pypy is a kind of cPython and might speed up the script dramatically by using pypy.
Gave a trial and installed pypy on ubuntu and used the shebang "#!/usr/bin pypy" where pypy is located.

Got permission denied. What's wrong?

Then i start manually, pypy complains about asyncio functions, maybe async is not supported in pypy?

Comment: any output running 'which pypy' ??

Comment: for the permission denied did you `chmod +x` your file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env pypy3` but pypy complains about `async def()`  anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The shebang should not contain a space between "bin" and "pypy", but a slash.

Comment: right? typing ```/usr/bin/env Python3```gives python shell, typing ```/usr/bin/env pypy```gives pypy shell.